# Not calculating correctly

Tags: c

So guys, I'm very new to programming and the C language, just learning it for fun :) So the Currnt is calculating quite right, it can calculate 4/2 but when I try 6/15 it just answers 0, any idea why?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main () {

    int Volt,Resst;
    float Currnt;

    printf("Enter the value of resistor:");
    scanf("%d",&Resst);
    printf("Enter the voltage of power supply:");
    scanf("%d",&Volt);
    if (Volt > 10)
    printf("The voltage is too big\n");
    else if (0 > Volt)
    printf("Not a valid input\n");
    else {
    Currnt=Volt/Resst;
    printf("The current is %.2f A\n",Currnt);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Its better if you post your code there, instead of just putting a picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an if/else statement block contains more than 1 command (like your last else branch), you need to use curly braces:

```
if (Volt > 10)
    printf("The voltage is too big");
else if (0 > Volt)
    printf("Not a valid input");
else {
    Current=Volt/Rest;
    printf("...");
}
```

To avoid errors like this, it is considered best practice to always use curly braces, even if there is only one command in a block:

```
if (Volt > 10) {
    printf("The voltage is too big");
}
else if (0 > Volt) {
    printf("Not a valid input");
}
else {
    Current=Volt/Rest;
    printf("...");
}
```

**UPDATE**

In C/C++ the type of the result of an expression (division in your case) is solely based on the type of the variables in it.
In your case the expression is `int / int`, so the result will be considered `int` - the type of the variable where you store it does not matter.
The solution is to explicitly cast at least one of the expression variables to `float`:

```
Currnt = (float)Volt/Resst;
```

or

```
Currnt = Volt/(float)Resst;
```

or

```
Currnt = (float)Volt/(float)Resst;
```

Comment: Hey dude, sorry to bother you again but I got another problem and I have to wait another day to ask another question, the Current=Volt/Rest isn't working quit well, it can do 4/2 but it can't do 6/15, any idea why?

Comment: Please edit your original question and post all your code.

Comment: Omg that was not in my book, spent way too much time looking for it hahah. Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

Because of your nesting, the `printf` is outside all the `if` conditions so you'll always see "The current is..."

Answer (score 0):

In any iterative or conditional statements,the compiler automatically assumes that the line directly after the statement is under the condition or iterative statement.

But if we want to run multiples lines under a condition it is necessary to use curly brackets to  tell the compiler to run all those line(s) under the condition